# Unix command or short python script to list files, but not relist files with a similar string?

Tags: unix

Assume you have a set of files:

```
a_1 a_2 a_3
b_1 b_2 b_3
c_1 c_2 c_3
```

Is there a way, through the command shell, to list part of each string and only list it once, i.e: a,b,c?

I know you can get it to list

```
a_1, b_1, c_1
```

but I want it to list only the first part of the string.

Comment: Do you mean something like `printf -- '%s\n' a_*` ?

Comment: want something like this:

a_(1-3)
b_(1-3)
c_(1_3)

Comment: when I wrote the question, I was thinking more long the lines of how `ls *_1` would give you `a_1 b_1 c_1`, but I was wondering if there is a way to maybe use an omit function like `ls -omit _*` and then lists `a b c`.

Comment: a folder with around 30 unique string prefixes, so like: `a1, a2, a3, ..., a30`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
cd /path/where/files/exists
printf -- '%s\n' a_[1-3] b_[1-3] c_[1_3]
```

or

```
cd /path/where/files/exists
ls -l a_[1-3] b_[1-3] c_[1_3]
```

or anything you want with [the globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Answer (score 0):

Unix shell is very powerful because of its pipeline design.

There isn't an `ls` option that will do what you're asking (that I'm aware of), but constructing a solution with pipelines is pretty easy.

```
ls | awk '{print sub(/_.*/, "", $0); print $0}' | sort -u
 |     |                              |            |
 |     |                              |            > sorts output and makes it unique
 |     |                              > prints what is left of each line, after sub
 |     > sub(...) turns a_...., into just 'a', etc
 > create you list of files
```

Sorry don't have time to build a test for this now. If you get syntax errors, please post as comments and I'll try to fix the code.

The one thing that's very "nard-coded" here is the regular expression `/_.*/` that will be removed. It means, "find the '_' char, and then all characters after that", then "replace them with the value in the `""`", which in this case is the empty string, effectively deleting the suffix part of the word. (try putting `"x"` instead of just `""` to see what I mean).

If your file list isn't quite as simple as your example, you will probably need to create a new reg-exp to substitute away the suffix part that you want removed.

If you're not familiar with pipelines, it is very easy to experiment, by adding one pipeline set at a time, to see how the output is modified by each step.
IHTH